# Django: Ajax validation of Crispy forms

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to get [Crispy forms Ajax validation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#ajax-validation-recipe) to work for my Django site, but I'm not sure how the errors are supposed to be displayed.  When I submit an invalid form, it appears that the JSON form that gets sent back is exactly the same as the original one, so I don't understand how the error response is supposed to happen.

The (abbreviated) view that gets called when the form button is pressed:

```
from crispy_forms.utils import render_crispy_form
from jsonview.decorators import json_view

@login_required
@json_view
def create_lab_device(request, owner):
    add_device_form = AddNewDeviceForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and add_device_form.is_valid():
        # do the stuff to save to database
        return {'success':True}
    # form not valid, return false with the rendered form
    form_html = render_crispy_form(add_device_form)
    return {'success':False, 'form_html':form_html}
```

The Crispy form sent in the original view:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Button
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineField

class AddNewDeviceForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddNewDeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'add-new-device-form'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Button('submit', 'Add', css_class='btn-default'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            InlineField('name'),
            InlineField('ip'),
        )

    name = forms.CharField(
        label="Name",
        max_length=30,
        required=True,
    )
    ip = forms.IPAddressField(
        label="IP Address",
        max_length=15,
        required=True,
    )
```

The javascript function that is called when the button is clicked:

```
function add_device_submit(){
    var form_id = '#add-new-device-form';
    $('#button-id-submit').on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "new/",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form_id).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if (!(data['success'])){
                    $(form_id).replaceWith(data['form_html']);
                } else {
                    $(form_id).find('.success-message').show();
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                $(form_id).find('.error-message').show();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

When I submit the form with just the 'name' field entered, I don't see anything different rendered on the page.  Using Firebug I can tell that the browser is re-rendering the form, but the data that it replaces is exactly the same as the original data created by the form.

How am I supposed to display the form errors?  The Crispy tutorial doesn't explain where the errors are supposed to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was stuck with a very similar problem recently, but I realized that reading about javascript and ajax in particular helped a lot.
Firstly, your view should be:

```
@login_required
def create_lab_device(request, owner):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      add_device_form = AddNewDeviceForm(request.POST)
      context_dict={}
      if response.is_ajax():
        add_device_form.is_valid():
        # do the stuff to save to database
        context_dict['success']=True
      else:
       # form not valid, return false with the rendered form
       context_dict['success']=False
return JsonResponse(context_dict)
```

Apart from this, the rendered form need not be sent back. Remember, the frontend already has a rendered form. Ajax is used because it reduces the need to render data. You could just reset the form if 'success' returns False.
Also note that you will not be able to send a GET request to this view. Next, I have used JsonResponse which works for Django 1.7+
For earlier versions,

```
   HttpResponse(json.dumps(context_dict), mimeType="application/json")
```

should be used.

```
success: function(data){
            if (!(data['success'])){
                $(form_id)[0].reset();
            } else {
                $(form_id).find('.success-message').show();
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            $(form_id).find('.error-message').show();
        }
```

Remember, error means that the ajax response was not received at all.